# Assert.equals() weird behavior does not recognize (apparently) equal strings

Tags: solidity, remix, testing, string

I'm facing problems related to string comparison using Assert.equals() provided by remix_tests.sol.

I made a toy contract and a related test to show what the problem is:

https://gist.github.com/brunoarruda/0cf813ee5aefe60427b5788e0489782e

When I run that test on Remix IDE with Solidity v0.5.1+commit.c8a2cb62, the last Assert comparing a string and another one built from its bytes32 counterpart does not pass. I put both strings inside assert message to see what was compared and the output is:

```
browser/test1_test.sol
1 failing

test_1 - Test user adding
Alice and Alice are not the same.
```

So, someone knows what is happening and how to make the string comparison work??

I tried to look for remix_tests.sol source code to study what was going on but I couldn't find it anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with your code is the `000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000` in `0x416c696365000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000` are also decoded with the character `\u0000`.

To fix that, you can use this function `bytes32ToString` to decode correctly without the zeros:

```
import "remix_tests.sol"; // this import is automatically injected by Remix.
import "./ContainerContract.sol";

contract test_1 {

    ContainerContract container;

    function beforeAll () public {
       container = new ContainerContract();
    }

    function testUserAdding() public returns (string memory) {
        // setup
        string memory name = "Alice";

        bytes32 nameBytes = 0x416c696365000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000;

        // processing
        container.addData(name);
        bytes32 recoveredNameBytes = container.data(0);
        string memory recoveredName = bytes32ToString(recoveredNameBytes);

        // asserting
        Assert.equal(nameBytes, recoveredNameBytes, "byte representations should be the same.");
        Assert.equal(name, name, "They should be literally the same.");
        string memory assertMsg = string(abi.encodePacked(name, " and ", recoveredName, " are not the same."));
        Assert.equal(name, recoveredName, assertMsg);
    }

    function bytes32ToString(bytes32 x) public returns (string memory value) {
        bytes memory bytesString = new bytes(32);
        uint charCount = 0;
        for (uint j = 0; j < 32; j++) {
            byte char = byte(bytes32(uint(x) * 2 ** (8 * j)));
            if (char != 0) {
                bytesString[charCount] = char;
                charCount++;
            }
        }
        bytes memory bytesStringTrimmed = new bytes(charCount);
        for (uint j = 0; j < charCount; j++) {
            bytesStringTrimmed[j] = bytesString[j];
        }
        value = string(bytesStringTrimmed);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just for clarification, `byte(bytes32(uint(x) * 2 ** (8 * j)))` takes the jth byte starting from the left, right? so with `x=nameBytes` and `j=0` it would pick `41`, correct??